# React native error undefined is not a function firebaseConfig

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm creating a react native project and using the firebase library. I import firebaseConfig from the firebase-config folder and initialize it to a constant, but an error occurs. What to do ?
main file

```js
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/auth';
import {firebaseConfig} from '../firebase-config';

export default function Register() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  const handleCreaceAccount = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('CREATE !!!!!!!');
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch(erorr => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

firebase-config

```js
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyBk_dM7c2rw9VE7HRtfxG3cY97KG7wdFTM',
  authDomain: 'zih-hal.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'zih-hal',
  storageBucket: 'zih-hal.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '353959046913',
  appId: '1:353959046913:web:2b6029d9ae04df5a32b500',
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong `import`. Convert

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/auth';
```

to

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```